# How to auto import in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have installed `VSCode Keymap` plugin in Android Studio. When I press `Command .` to import `Text` composable it says `org.w3c.dom.Text? (multiple choices...) ⌘.`. In vscode if there were multiple classes with same name then it would show me a dropdown to choose what class to import.

How can I do the same in Android Studio? I am on macOS Big Sur with Android Studio 2020.3.1 Beta 3.

[image]

Comment: Try with `alt`+`intro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press optionKey & Enter (or return key) together

```
⌥ ↩
```

[image]